# PostgreSQL in VSCode gives an Uncaught Error: Requested method is unsupported: credential/save

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-code

When I try to connect to my PostgreSQL database in VSCode I get an Uncaught Error: Requested method is unsupported: credential/save. I can't find anything to solve this issue. Does anyone know how I can access my PostgreSQL database in VSCode?
Some extra info:

- I'm using PostgreSQL version 16.1
- VSCode version 1.84.2
- Running Windows 10 Home

I have tried to google the error code but found nothing. I have made sure PostgreSQL is installed and included in PATH. Restarted VSCode multiple times, even reinstalled the PostgreSQL extension.

I'm using [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-ossdata.vscode-postgresql) extension (the Microsoft PostgreSQL extension).

To connect, I type ctrl + shift + p and select "PostgreSQL: New Query". Then I fill in the correct info there and while in my bottom right corner it looks as if I'm connected, I don't get a PostgreSQL icon in my activity bar and can't access or create any databases.

Comment: Looks like this [was reported as an issue in late September](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-postgresql/issues/122). It might be worth commenting on that issue to see if the project maintainers reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your database in VS Code, you can use the integrated terminal as an alternative means. Open your terminal right inside VS Code by selecting View > Terminal (or select `` Ctrl+` `` , using the backtick character).Run `psql <your-cluster-name>`.